# List Writng to a List to promote next item

Tags: auto-populate

I have a InfoPath form that auto-populates items from another list. Information is pulling just fine into the form but I have 2 problems. The one I would like to resolve first is the status. Initially the list that is pulling form has a status blank. I will like the form to write back to list updating the status and pushing the next blank item to work with. Any ideas???

2nd problem is that of auto-population of issues. I would like to auto populate by item id first then by issue id. However, and item id may have up to 6 issues id that may need different status.

New with the tools guys. Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help, I've done something similar...

So you will need to have the list that you are writing to and the required columns imported as a data connection. (If you are writing to list items in the same list, you will still need to import this as a secondary connection, even though it's also your main, as you're writing to OTHER items, not the current.)

Then, you will need an indexed column (unique identifier) and a way of referring to a particular list item, and finally a column that store the ID of the filtered item it found (I just use the id for the indexed column, and then I have a hidden string field that it will search for using a filter looking for that string, and store the ID of that found item in the ID column of the current item.)

Then, just use a workflow to edit the item in the other list, using the ID.

(This sounds awfully complicated, but I havent found a way to edit an item in another list from the form itself, only by creating a new item and running a workflow from its creation.)

(If creating a new item is not desirable, you could simply set the workflow to "delete current item" if the current item meets a criterion, eg. if title is set to "deleteme" - which you'd set in the form.)